# Android Studio 3: no AVD manager and no Tools->Android menu after install on new machine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Downloaded and installed Android Studio 3 today on a Mac. Created a new blank Android app. After creating and fixing this in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

(caused "Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26'...") to:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

And building succcessfully, there is still no AVD manager available. I've seen about 4 questions about this on here but none of them have fixed it. Spent half an hour trying various things. What is the problem?

Also, after downloading the tools directly there are still no AVDs:

```
~/Downloads/tools/emulator -list-avds # no output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typed all that and at the end thought I'd double check that ANDROID_HOME wasn't the issue. Well, it was. So:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
export export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

And restart Android Studio.

I wish the Android team would remind you about that.